# protect urls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some pages in a rails website that can be accessed only by user and admin,
I am hiding them from the public inside the views with user_signed_in?.

the problem is that when you copy and paste the url of the page when not logged in
you can still access them.

I imagine its something I need to add in the controller of those pages.

Any help would be great as I am still learning rails.

for example i would like to protect this controller

```
class DailiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_daily, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /dailies
  # GET /dailies.json
  def index
    @dailies = Daily.order("created_at desc")
 end

  # GET /dailies/1
  # GET /dailies/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /dailies/new
  def new
    @daily = current_admin.dailies.new
  end

  # GET /dailies/1/edit
  def edit
    @daily = current_admin.dailies.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /dailies
  # POST /dailies.json
  def create
    @daily = current_admin.dailies.new(daily_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @daily.save
        format.html { redirect_to @daily, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @daily }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @daily.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /dailies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /dailies/1.json
  def update
    @daily = current_admin.dailies.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @daily.update(daily_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @daily, notice: 'daily was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @daily.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /dailies/1
  # DELETE /dailies/1.json
  def destroy
    @daily = current_admin.dailies.find(params[:id])

    @daily.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to dailies_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_daily
      @daily = Daily.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def daily_params
      params.require(:daily).permit(:description, :image)
    end

end
```

Comment: What are you checking in your method (authenticate_admin)?

Comment: nothing at the moment, I tried !admins_signed_in? in the method but that didnt work

Comment: That's the thing. You have to implement the method authenticate_admin, for example by storing the user data on the session, in that way if the user data it is not in the session, then it is not allowed to do those actions.

Comment: thanks that works but I would have to do it for both admins and user, how can I blend them in one method, user_signed in || or admin_signed_in ?

Comment: I suppose you will need two filters, because the user should have access to some resources that not necessarily are the same than the admin.

Comment: yes I imagined that but lets say I want to show index to both users and admin without having to be signed_in as both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70475/discussion-between-facundofarias-and-herman-eduard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you already created a method called authenticate_admin?

you can try something like this

```
before_action :has_access?

    def has_access?
      redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?
    end
```